# How much can gravity affect light frequency?

Tags: general-relativity, radio-frequency

I was wondering, maybe SETI cannot catch alien radio signals, because they don't monitor the right wavelengths. What if aliens live near a black hole or a denser region and radio signals coming from there redshift, so they will be ultra low frequency when they arrive here. I was wondering how much it is possible to red or blue shift this kind of communication. Is it only a small effect, or can it be something bigger that affects detection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gravitational redshift near a black hole is $\sqrt{1-R_s/R}$ (that is, frequencies get downshifted by this factor). The innermost stable circular orbit is $3R_s$, so the redshift from there is $\sqrt{2/3}=0.81$. Not enormous. Would turn a 1 GHz signal into a 810 MHz signal, blue light into blue-green light.

The redshift from expansion on the other hand downshifts frequencies by $1/(1+z)$. This is OK for nearby galaxies, but [CR7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_Redshift_7) has $z=6.6$ and would hence downshift frequencies by a factor 0.13. That would turn blue light into infrared.

In practice SETI does not attempt to detect extragalactic signals since it is hard enough to do it inside the galaxy. Black hole civilizations would presumably be energetic enough that we might notice their other activities.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks!